# App signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. Yes it does

Tags: ios, xcode5, apple-push-notifications

Havind added push notifications to my app, Im getting this message  when uploading my binary

`app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement`

However my distribution provisioning profile it clearly does have this entitlement.

All green in the portal for my app ID configured for push notifications.

Certificate is set to `production` for push notifications.

I have deleted and re downloaded provisioning profile, still get same message

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was signing  before upload to Appstore with wrong provisioning profile that looked similar to a previous version before push notification was added.

Answer (score 2):

The provisioning profile you chose in the Distribute step may have the entitlement, but your app may not. Check that the provisioning profile chosen by Xcode in the Archive phase (Release configuration) includes the entitlement. An error here will not be fixed in the Distribute step, no matter what profile/code signing identity you choose there.

You can check the Release phase's output by Revealing the app in Finder, and running

```
codesign -d --entitlements - your.app
```

If the release version is ok, run the same on the Distribute
version too.

Comment: The release configuration includes the profile with the correct entitlements

Comment: So Release and Distribute reference exactly the version of the right profile?

Comment: If i have understood you correctly - Release (in code provisioning section) is set to the distribution profile that contains the `"aps-environment" entitlement`

Comment: revealing the app in finder?

Comment: actually, check the entitlements of the Archived version, before and after Distribution

Comment: I can only open the plist of the archived version, I cant check the entitlements of the archived version. trying to find a way round this.

Comment: you need to run codesign on the app, see the answer for how

Comment: I dont understand what your answer means "run codesign on the app" Ive revealed the archive in finder now what do I do with ``codesign -d --entitlements - your.app???

Comment: Right click on archive > show contents of package and navigate to app (it's in there!)

Comment: The `embeded.mobileprovision` certificate from the archived app DOES contain  the `aps-environment` entitlement.  Why am i being told its not there by Apple? Its in the archived app??

Comment: @RhythmicFistman what *should* the `codesign ...` command reveal for a valid release? What key/value are you looking for, `aps-environment`?

Comment: You should see `<key>aps-environment</key><string>production</string>` in the `Entitlements` dictionary.

Comment: Was running into this same issue, and discovered an Xcode update had apparently dropped Push Notifications from my Target's Capability list. Just had to re-add it, hope that helps someone.